# как вернуть пользователя на предыдушую активность при нажатию на кнопку

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent

Есть кнопка, которая есть во всех окнах и переадресирует на новую активность, но как вернуться на ту активность где нажали кнопку? Системная кнопка "назад" отпадает, так как она скрыта

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например если вы переходите на другую активность таким образом:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

то можно сделать просто `finish()` и все.

Comment: допустим у меня 5 милионов страниц на каждой из них есть кнопка которая перенаправляет на другую активность. Что в таком случае делать?

Comment: кнопкой назад вы завершаете конечную активность, она перестает быть последней в стеке, и вы возвращаетесь на предпоследнюю с которой и был осуществлен переход, но хочу заметить если у вас как вы выразились 5М страниц, в вашем случае активностей, то лучше пересмотреть архитектуру приложения